# Engineering calculations in a tool that will handle units

Tags: software, unit

I know [Mathcad](https://www.mathcad.com/en) handles units along with numbers which makes it easier to avoid errors by tracking units the way we would by hand.

```
e.g. 250 kW + 500 W
```

I just wanted to compare tools before I switch to Mathcad. Are there  any other tools people are aware of which will handle units as well?

I am especially interested in free / open source alternative that could do this unit-tracking either natively or with a Plugin.

e.g. Python or Jupyter notebooks etc.

If I must go with a paid version then Mathcad (or Mathcad Express, its free cousin) works as well unless there's a paid competitor that had more features or ease of use.

Comment: WolframAlpha and by extension it’s bigger brother Mathematica (now called Wolfram One I think?) can do this

Comment: @SolarMike Indeed! I always do this by hand so far but moving to a software like MathCad which can handle this natively seems an improvement from just using Excel and then validating the units by hand. Also in Excel the formula itself remains a bit opaque.

Comment: I don't know what you are after next to the units support, but if just need numerical calculations, basic graphing and units this https://www.speqmath.com/ is simple, light and great.

Comment: Mathematica incorrectly called wolfram one has many dedicated functions for handling units and can directly numerically solve

Comment: I'd echo the importance of knowing dimensional analysis. I'm not sure about this since I don't use it but I seem to recall that the Boost libraries for C++ have ways of enforcing this.

Comment: Adding me to the list of those who emphasize the importance of knowing dimensional analysis. Another thing is considering writing a calculation with consistent units elevates its readability (even a bad report). I frequently reject this type of work and send it back to the coworkers for the slopiness that demonstrate they do not rely on their knowledge but black box .software.

Comment: your question about available software belongs at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in using Python, check out the [`pint`](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [`astropy.units`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/) or [`unyt`](https://github.com/yt-project/unyt) packages. I have personally used `pint` + `jupyter` for day-to-day engineering in the past, and have looked at the others and they all should be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

No one seems to have suggested this, but Google search bar handles mixed units just fine.  You can type "(25 pounds mass)(7 m/s^2) in dynes" and it'll give it to you.  If you don't specify the output it typically defaults to SI.  You can even say things like (Planck's constant)*(speed of light)/(700 nm) and it will give you the energy.

Downside is you don't have a nice record of your calculations, but for quick things I use it in my job all the time

Answer (score 1):

Another great free tool that work very well and its a clone of MathCad (so you won't have to relearn something) is [SMath Studio](https://en.smath.com/view/SMathStudio/summary)

As I've mentioned up until now its free (although I think its closed source).

If you were using Mathcad before and you liked it, I guarantee that you will love this.

For me, although I work day to day with Python, this is the go to place for me when I want to make a quick calculation and I'm worried about units consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There are good and extensive examples using *unyt* module for Python.
Check out this: Working with unyt-unvt v2.8.0 documentation.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

For everyday use, basically as my desktop "pocket" calculator, I use [Qalculate!](http://qalculate.github.io/downloads.html)

The look and feel is like a pocket calculator, under the hood it's a computer algebra sytem. It handles units just fine and allows you to force output in a specific unit by typing the calcualtipon you want as an equation, for example you could type  `a * b / c = x kWh` if `a * b / c` would return a result in J and you want kWh.

Answer (score 0):

[EngineeringPaper.xyz](https://engineeringpaper.xyz) is a free online web app for engineering calculations that can handle units. It uses a notebook format to organize the calculation.